# Generalizing a collection method

Tags: scala, collections, higher-kinded-types

If I want to generalize the following method to all collection types that support all the necessary operations (`foldLeft`, `flatMap`, `map`, and `:+`) then how do I do it? Currently it only works with lists.

Code:

```
def join[A](lists: List[List[A]]): List[List[A]] = {
  lists.foldLeft(List(List[A]())) { case (acc, cur) =>
    for {
      a <- acc
      c <- cur
    } yield a :+ c
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want this only for collections that support `:+`, the easiest way is just to define it in terms of `Seq` instead of `List`.

You *can* make it a lot more generic, all the way down to `Traversable`, by using builders.  I'd be happy to explain that when I have a bit more time on my hands, but it tends to get complicated at that level.

Scalaz applicative functors is probably the way to go, but I'll let someone with more Scalaz experience than me handle that particular answer.